# Power steering pump not sucking fluid

Tags: power-steering, gmc, yukon

Just replaced the PS pump in a 05 Yukon Denali with a remanufactured one. During the bleeding process, lock to lock many times with engine off, the resevoir on the pump never seemed to suck down any fluid.

After replacement the power steering and brakes no longer work. This vehicle does have a hydroboost unit. Prior to replacing the pump the steering and brakes did work.

The reason for the pump replacement is there was a leak somewhere, and on a few occasions the vehicle was driven with no PS fluid which assuming damaged the pump.

My question is, does this sound like a bad remanufactured pump or are there other components I can check?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you ran it? Not sure on this one ... usually to bleed the system, you need to have the front end off the ground (on jack stands or what have you), reservoir full, *start the engine*, then run the steering lock to lock several times to bleed. Doing it without running isn't going to get you much.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I ended up letting the vehicle run for about an hour, and then it worked flawlessly. What do you think caused it to start working? Prior to letting it run for a while the steering wheel and brakes were extremely stiff (not drivable whatsoever)

Comment: It sounds as though the system bled out and things started working. You'll want to check the reservoir to ensure it is up to level.

Comment: @David feel free to [answer your own question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) here. This way you can help out others who may have the same question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a proper bleeding by rotating steering wheel lock to lock many times, letting the engine idle for a while solved the issue for me.